# Need suggestions regarding K-Means text clustering in Mahout 0.9

Tags: java, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, mahout, k-means

I am trying to cluster Educations. The data entries got a name and a description, like this:

> MSc Aeronautical Engineering
>
> The master´s programme in Aeronautical Engineering at Linköping
>   University offers a holistic view on aircraft design. An aircraft is a
>   complex, integrated, closely connected system of various technologies
>   and disciplines such as: aerodynamics, structure, propulsion,
>   actuation systems and other on-board systems. All these disciplines
>   need to be optimized in order to achieve the function and the
>   efficiency required in an aircraft. The programme involves a project
>   in the later part when all these disciplines come together and
>   challenge students to design, build and fly an aircraft, or a subscale
>   version of it.

I make sequence files from my lucene index:

```
LuceneStorageConfiguration luceneStorageConf = new LuceneStorageConfiguration(conf, 
        Arrays.asList(indexFilesPath), sequenceFilesPath, "name",
        Arrays.asList("name", "description"));

SequenceFilesFromLuceneStorage sequenceFilefromLuceneStorage = new SequenceFilesFromLuceneStorage();
sequenceFilefromLuceneStorage.run(luceneStorageConf);
```

I then generate sparsevectors. I set my `args` to the correct paths, a MaxDFSigma to 5 and sequential true. Im don't know if this parameters are correct for my purpose.

```
ToolRunner.run(new SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles(), args);
```

I am then running the CanopyDriver to generete input clusters to K-means. I put Tanimoto distance since I read that it is good for text clustering. T1 distance metric to 3.1, T2 distance metric 2.1, run clustering false, cluster classification threshold to 0, and run sequential true.

```
CanopyDriver.run(conf,
                 tfidfVectorsPath,
                 outputPath,
                 new TanimotoDistanceMeasure(),
                 3.1,
                 2.1,
                 false,
                 0.0,
                 true);
```

Last I run K-Means, with a convergence delta set to 0.001, max iterations 10, run clustering true, cluster classification threshold to 0 and run sequential true:

```
KMeansDriver.run(conf, 
                 tfidfVectorsPath,
                 new Path(outputPath,"clusters-0-final"),
                 kmeansOutput,
                 0.001,
                 10,
                 true,
                 0.0,
                 false);
```

I can print out my clusters like this:

```
IntWritable key = new IntWritable();
WeightedPropertyVectorWritable value = new WeightedPropertyVectorWritable();
while (reader.next(key, value)) {
    System.out.println("Cluster " + key.toString() + " got the following vector " + value.toString());
}
reader.close();
```

An this is what it prints out:

```
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.861373565304716  vec: Acting = [1:2.735, 4:4.441, 5:4.441, 13:2.165, 25:2.224, 26:2.224, 30:1.754, 35:2.447, 36:2.735, 51:2.447, 116:2.735, 118:1.887, 174:2.480, 178:2.447, 179:2.735, 187:2.735, 205:2.447, 224:2.735, 240:2.735, 242:3.460, 248:2.447, 260:2.041, 267:1.887]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.868019533374171  vec: Adult Learning and Global Change = [30:1.754, 34:2.447, 43:2.735, 56:2.447, 72:2.447, 80:2.735, 105:3.460, 106:2.735, 117:2.735, 142:2.447, 143:2.447, 148:2.447, 173:2.735, 176:2.447, 181:2.735, 199:2.735, 203:2.224, 214:2.447, 233:2.447, 247:2.735, 262:2.735, 268:3.460]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.8630506879479874  vec: Agricultural Economics and Management = [8:5.469, 9:4.736, 21:2.447, 28:2.735, 29:2.735, 31:2.447, 33:2.735, 34:2.447, 39:2.735, 60:2.447, 70:2.735, 71:5.439, 94:2.447, 108:2.447, 111:2.447, 136:2.447, 149:3.460, 152:1.754, 167:2.735, 171:2.735, 189:2.447, 203:2.224, 206:2.224, 210:4.441, 242:2.447, 249:3.460, 257:2.735, 273:2.480]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.8382953832498294  vec: Agroecology = [2:4.441, 3:2.447, 8:2.735, 9:4.736, 10:4.441, 12:2.735, 25:3.852, 26:3.145, 27:2.041, 30:1.754, 32:4.441, 44:2.447, 56:2.447, 61:2.735, 64:3.460, 69:2.735, 70:2.735, 79:2.447, 82:2.735, 83:4.441, 85:2.735, 86:4.441, 87:2.041, 93:2.447, 94:2.447, 105:2.447, 110:2.447, 118:1.887, 121:2.224, 128:2.735, 131:2.735, 133:1.887, 137:2.735, 139:1.636, 143:3.460, 144:4.441, 148:3.460, 152:1.754, 155:2.447, 165:2.735, 166:2.447, 167:2.735, 170:2.447, 171:2.735, 178:2.447, 182:2.735, 187:3.867, 189:4.894, 192:3.814, 198:3.867, 199:2.735, 202:1.636, 203:3.852, 206:2.224, 214:2.447, 215:2.447, 216:4.441, 226:3.775, 227:2.447, 228:2.041, 229:4.441, 230:2.224, 231:3.145, 237:2.224, 243:3.460, 248:2.447, 252:2.447, 254:2.735, 260:2.041, 263:2.224, 264:2.735, 267:1.887, 269:2.735]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.8546104020199703  vec: Analytical Finance = [14:2.447, 15:3.867, 65:2.735, 72:2.447, 78:2.447, 89:5.439, 90:4.441, 97:3.145, 100:3.145, 133:2.669, 142:2.447, 149:2.447, 151:2.735, 183:2.447, 184:2.735, 192:2.335, 212:2.735, 268:2.447, 273:3.038]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.8525453440258359  vec: Animal Science = [13:1.531, 16:7.021, 17:7.021, 27:2.041, 30:1.754, 42:2.735, 74:2.041, 85:2.735, 94:2.447, 98:2.447, 107:2.447, 108:2.447, 110:2.447, 111:2.447, 112:2.735, 119:4.441, 121:2.224, 133:1.887, 174:1.754, 175:5.471, 183:2.447, 189:2.447, 191:2.224, 202:2.314, 205:2.447, 207:2.669, 208:2.735, 217:4.441, 243:2.447, 251:4.441, 255:2.735, 259:3.460, 260:2.041, 261:2.447, 266:2.735, 267:1.887, 273:1.754]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.8691568007982957  vec: Animated Film = [0:2.735, 13:1.531, 18:6.280, 35:2.447, 48:2.735, 52:3.867, 63:2.735, 117:2.735, 129:2.735, 164:2.224, 190:2.447, 232:2.735, 242:2.447, 247:2.735, 252:2.447, 253:2.735, 257:2.735, 259:3.460, 264:2.735, 267:3.269, 273:2.480]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.845250503777627  vec: Applied English linguistics = [6:2.447, 13:1.531, 20:2.887, 23:1.754, 29:2.735, 53:2.224, 54:2.735, 63:2.735, 74:2.041, 78:5.994, 81:2.735, 88:2.447, 93:2.447, 101:2.735, 103:2.735, 129:2.735, 138:2.735, 139:1.636, 140:6.115, 146:5.439, 154:2.735, 159:2.041, 164:2.224, 170:2.447, 174:1.754, 192:2.335, 196:2.447, 200:2.735, 202:1.636, 214:2.447, 215:2.447, 223:4.441, 228:2.041, 246:2.735, 254:2.735, 263:3.145, 269:2.735]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.8441577500264077  vec: Applied Mathematics Programme = [13:1.531, 20:2.887, 23:1.754, 26:2.224, 37:2.735, 47:2.447, 53:3.852, 59:5.439, 68:2.735, 72:3.460, 77:2.041, 78:2.447, 87:2.041, 88:2.447, 103:2.735, 104:4.441, 107:2.447, 114:2.735, 116:2.735, 139:2.314, 142:2.447, 152:1.754, 156:4.441, 157:8.881, 158:2.735, 159:2.887, 161:2.735, 163:2.735, 168:2.735, 182:2.735, 184:2.735, 191:4.973, 192:1.348, 193:3.460, 207:1.887, 218:2.735, 221:4.441, 227:4.894, 228:2.887, 241:2.735, 252:3.460, 260:2.041, 272:2.735, 273:4.960]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.8214250552767353  vec: Applied Mechanics = [6:2.447, 13:1.531, 14:2.447, 20:2.887, 31:2.447, 42:2.735, 43:2.735, 46:2.735, 64:2.447, 66:2.447, 74:2.887, 77:3.536, 84:4.238, 93:2.447, 97:2.224, 107:2.447, 120:2.735, 121:2.224, 125:2.735, 127:2.735, 134:2.735, 136:2.447, 139:1.636, 155:2.447, 158:3.867, 162:3.145, 168:2.735, 174:1.754, 183:2.447, 186:2.447, 190:2.447, 192:1.907, 196:2.447, 202:1.636, 204:4.736, 213:2.735, 226:1.887, 235:4.441, 243:2.447, 256:2.735, 267:1.887]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.8705019419490072  vec: Applied Physics = [20:2.041, 23:1.754, 25:2.224, 46:2.735, 57:2.447, 76:2.735, 77:2.041, 82:2.735, 84:2.447, 100:2.224, 162:2.224, 177:2.735, 180:6.280, 181:2.735, 192:1.348, 219:3.867, 232:2.735, 237:2.224, 238:2.735]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.8549884296474971  vec: Aquatic Ecology Master Programme = [3:2.447, 6:3.460, 13:1.531, 19:2.735, 21:2.447, 22:7.692, 23:1.754, 27:2.041, 30:1.754, 33:2.735, 41:4.441, 44:2.447, 54:2.735, 55:4.441, 57:2.447, 65:2.735, 68:2.735, 69:6.698, 73:2.735, 74:2.887, 79:2.447, 87:2.887, 88:2.447, 91:2.735, 96:4.441, 97:3.145, 98:2.447, 100:2.224, 114:3.867, 118:1.887, 123:4.238, 132:2.735, 133:1.887, 135:4.441, 139:2.314, 149:3.460, 150:7.021, 152:2.480, 154:2.735, 160:4.441, 162:2.224, 164:2.224, 169:2.735, 172:2.735, 186:2.447, 192:2.335, 194:2.224, 200:2.735, 202:2.834, 203:4.448, 207:2.669, 209:2.735, 213:2.735, 219:2.735, 226:2.669, 231:3.145, 236:2.735, 239:4.441, 246:2.735, 250:2.735, 258:4.441, 271:2.735, 272:3.867]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.8441981452499265  vec: Astronomy: Master's Degree Project = [3:2.447, 13:1.531, 27:2.041, 30:1.754, 37:2.735, 52:3.867, 57:2.447, 60:2.447, 102:4.441, 139:1.636, 147:2.735, 153:2.224, 159:2.041, 165:2.735, 172:2.735, 185:5.439, 194:3.145, 202:1.636, 204:3.867, 224:2.735, 228:2.041, 237:2.224, 245:2.735, 248:2.447, 263:2.224, 271:2.735, 273:3.508, 274:3.867]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.8312263297298608  vec: Atmospheric Science, Master's Programme = [13:1.531, 15:2.735, 23:2.480, 24:7.021, 26:2.224, 34:4.238, 39:3.867, 56:2.447, 58:2.447, 61:2.735, 62:2.224, 64:2.447, 66:2.447, 73:3.867, 75:4.441, 79:2.447, 81:2.735, 84:2.447, 87:2.041, 99:2.735, 105:3.460, 110:2.447, 112:2.735, 118:2.669, 121:2.224, 122:2.447, 123:4.238, 130:2.447, 131:2.735, 133:1.887, 136:2.447, 139:1.636, 147:2.735, 153:2.224, 155:2.447, 159:2.041, 161:2.735, 174:2.480, 175:2.447, 179:2.735, 188:4.441, 191:2.224, 192:1.348, 195:2.735, 202:1.636, 207:3.775, 220:2.735, 225:2.735, 228:2.041, 230:2.224, 244:4.441, 249:4.238, 253:2.735, 260:2.041, 266:2.735]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.8410581023430623  vec: Computer Science, Master's Programme = [1:3.867, 14:2.447, 19:2.735, 20:2.041, 23:3.038, 27:2.041, 28:3.867, 30:1.754, 31:2.447, 35:2.447, 36:2.735, 38:4.441, 40:2.735, 45:4.441, 47:7.341, 48:3.867, 49:5.469, 50:2.735, 51:2.447, 53:3.145, 58:2.447, 60:2.447, 62:4.973, 67:4.441, 74:2.887, 76:2.735, 77:2.041, 92:4.441, 95:4.441, 97:3.852, 99:2.735, 100:2.224, 101:2.735, 106:2.735, 108:3.460, 109:4.441, 111:3.460, 113:4.441, 115:4.441, 118:1.887, 122:2.447, 123:2.447, 124:3.140, 125:3.867, 126:2.735, 130:2.447, 132:2.735, 133:1.887, 134:2.735, 137:2.735, 139:1.636, 141:2.735, 143:2.447, 145:5.439, 148:2.447, 151:2.735, 152:1.754, 153:3.145, 159:2.041, 162:2.224, 164:4.448, 169:2.735, 175:3.460, 177:2.735, 178:2.447, 186:2.447, 190:3.460, 191:2.224, 192:3.015, 193:5.471, 194:2.224, 195:2.735, 196:2.447, 197:4.441, 198:2.735, 201:2.735, 202:3.272, 206:2.224, 207:5.968, 211:2.735, 212:2.735, 215:3.460, 218:3.867, 220:2.735, 225:2.735, 226:1.887, 227:2.447, 230:2.224, 231:4.973, 234:2.735, 236:4.736, 240:2.735, 249:2.447, 259:3.460, 261:2.447, 262:2.735, 263:3.145, 265:5.439, 267:2.669, 270:5.439, 273:5.546, 274:3.867]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.8527476806601426  vec: MSc Aeronautical Engineering = [7:4.441, 11:6.280, 12:3.867, 40:2.735, 44:2.447, 50:2.735, 62:3.145, 66:4.238, 77:2.887, 98:2.447, 128:2.735, 152:1.754, 166:2.447, 170:2.447, 173:2.735, 174:1.754, 176:2.447, 192:1.907, 194:2.224, 201:2.735, 206:2.224, 226:1.887, 230:2.224, 231:3.145, 233:2.447, 245:2.735, 250:2.735, 255:2.735, 256:2.735, 261:2.447]
Cluster 0 got the following vector wt: 1.0 distance: 0.8189710533774026  vec: Master Programme in Computer Science = [0:2.735, 21:2.447, 23:1.754, 25:2.224, 47:7.341, 49:3.867, 51:2.447, 53:3.145, 58:2.447, 62:3.145, 80:2.735, 87:2.041, 91:2.735, 118:1.887, 120:2.735, 122:2.447, 126:2.735, 127:2.735, 130:2.447, 138:2.735, 140:2.735, 141:2.735, 152:2.480, 153:2.224, 163:2.735, 166:2.447, 174:1.754, 176:2.447, 192:2.335, 193:3.460, 205:2.447, 207:4.220, 208:2.735, 209:2.735, 211:2.735, 222:3.140, 226:1.887, 233:2.447, 234:4.736, 237:3.852, 238:2.735, 241:2.735, 268:2.447]
```

All educations are ending up in the same cluster. I have tried with different distance measures but it does not help, I have tried with different max iterations (up to 100) but with the same result.
As we can see they all have a distance between 81-87, is this why they end up in the same cluster? When using other distance measures the span is bigger but they are still all in the same cluster. Do I need to remove more terms that are of no value for the characteristics of the course? How do I look at my top terms?

Long post and a lot of questions, I would be really glad for some help on this.

Thank you!

Comment: Unless you have several millions of vectors, try *not using Mahout*. As long as your data fits into main memory, or the Lucene index of a single machine, use an implementation optimized for a single computer, not for *thousands* of computers (which you don't have or make good use of). In my experiments, Mahout k-means was 10x slower running on 20 CPUs, than a good single CPU solution. I'm not kidding, try yourself. Consider using Carrot, Orange, or ELKI instead.

Comment: How big is the data set? Is it available somewhere to try out suggestions before posting them here? I found k-means results to be next to meaningless, so I'm not surprised to see them not work for you.

Comment: My dataset is not that big but I want my solution to be future proof. So, you don't think I will get good clustering results using K-means on this kind of data? Is Carrot easy to get started with and does it have any algorithms that you think would give good results with this kind of text dataset? Thank you for your input

Comment: Do you really think the data set will *ever* be more than 128 GB? Which is the amount of RAM an upper range server has these days, without using SSD storage. I have never used Carrot or Orange, I cannot comment on these two, but they seem to be better tools for your use case.

Comment: No you are right, will probably not be bigger than that. I am trying out Carrot workbench now, seems promising, and getting pretty good results using K-Means. Will try to find some examples using Carrot in Java code, if it's not too complicated I will consider switch over to that.

Comment: I'm a happy user of ELKI; which is a good choice if you like programming in Java. But I havn't used text data much, so I don't know how well optimized the code in ELKI is for text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading up on my methods. I figured out that I didn't tweak my parameters for the CanopyDriver enough. From the book Mahout in Action I read that:

"Canopy clustering doesn’t require you to
specify the number of cluster centroids as a
parameter. The number of centroids formed
depends only on the choice of the distance
measures, T1 and T2"

It turned out to give me really good results!

Comment: You could use the [RandomSeedGenerator](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/mrlegacy/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/clustering/kmeans/RandomSeedGenerator.java) class to pick the initial centroids.